# Primes $2^n-n-2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is $3$ the only natural number $n$ such that $2^n - n - 2$ is prime?

If there is another, it is greater than $2 \times 10^4$; of course it must be odd, but not a prime, and not divisible by $3$.  I don't think there can be an elementary proof that $2^n-n-2$ must be divisible by something related to $n$, because e.g.  the least prime factor of $2^{323}-325$ is $2017403$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the above question but I know that $2^n-3$ is a prime many times.

Comment: Sequence is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A000247 (but I don't know whether any of the links and references there will help with the current question).

Comment: This expression is more "natural" than my sum over $j!^{j!}$ in which case I was baffled that OEIS conatins it , but as Gerry points out that this does not always actually help to answer the question. It would be better if not only the OEIS-link is mentioned, but that the conclusion what this helps (search limit, mentioned conjectures etc.) would also be pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Serge Batalov points out [here](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=418970&postcount=2), $2^{39137}-39137-2$ and $2^{59819}-59819-2$ are both probable primes.  According to the links there, both were discovered by Henri Lifchitz in 2005.  They have 11782 and 18008 digits respectively, so someone with the right hardware and software should be able to prove their primality using ECPP.

(For what it's worth, I found the first using OpenPFGW, and googling it led me to the link above.)

Comment: The second number could be barely in the reach of ECPP. It is probably below the record that has been achieved , but it will be a timeconsuming task. Did the author mention which tests the given numbers passes ?

Comment: @Peter Time depends on how many threads you have at your disposal, of course.  My rough understanding is that Andreas Enge's CM can prove a number of this size in a few days on a cluster of fast computers, or probably a few months on a more typical computer.

Comment: Interesting , I was not aware of the fact that ECPP can be parallized , that is surprising. Did the author apply Miller Rabin ? If yes, with how many bases ?

Comment: And I don't know about Lifchitz, but my PFGW run only did base-3 PRP tests.  (I've now continued to 100k+ with no new PRPs yet.)  Of course, further PRP tests on numbers of this size should finish pretty much instantaneously.

Comment: I know PFGW , the search limit in this short time is impressive, I guess my computer would take much longer.

Comment: What I meant is whether Miller Rabin was used to establish the found primes as probable primes. Of course, to find them, a single test is used (usually even a weak test)

Comment: I've told you all I know about the PRPs.  And I wouldn't count your computer out--I'm using an almost 7-year-old laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140781/discussion-between-ravi-fernando-and-peter).